# What would $\hat{\Sigma}_0$ equal to?

Tags: statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,...,X_{n_1}$ be an i.i.d. sample from $N_p(\mu_1,\Sigma)$ and let $Y_1,...,Y_{n_2}$ be an independent sample from $N_p(\mu_2,\Sigma)$, for some $\mu_1,\mu_2 \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and some invertible, $p\times p$ positive definite matrix $\Sigma$.

Suppose $H_0 : \mu_1=\mu_2$.

I calculated that $$\hat{\mu_0}=\frac{\sum^{n_1}_{i=1}x_i+\sum^{n_2}_{i=1}y_i}{n_1+n_2}$$

What would $\hat{\Sigma}_0$ equal to?

Would it be equal to

$$\hat{\Sigma_0}=\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}\biggl(\sum^{n_1}_{i=1}(x_i-\hat{\mu_0})(x_1-\hat{\mu_0})^T+\sum^{n_2}_{i=1}(y_i-\hat{\mu_0})(y_i-\hat{\mu_0})^T\biggr)?$$

Comment: Are you assuming $\Sigma$ is known? If so you don't need to estimate it.

Comment: @MatthewPilling assume it's unknown!

Comment: Your $\hat{\Sigma}_0$ is the ML estimator of $\Sigma$ (with $n_1+n_2$ in the denominator).